# Dell U2711 monitor USB hub does not recognize/auto-mount USB disks

Tags: usb, monitor

I recently purchased a Dell u2711 display.
The monitor works well in Ubuntu 11.10, that is, auto recognized and working at full resolution with the included DVI-D (dual link) cable.

My problem is that the monitor's built in USB hub does not recognize USB disks and devices.  These disks and devices work perfectly if plugged into the computer directly.

Has anyone encountered this problem?  If so, has anyone devised a solution?
Thanks

EDIT: The monitor hub is connected to tested and functional USB ports on the computer.

EDIT: DVD-D to DVI-D cable

Comment: Just to make sure: did you connect the monitor's USB port to your PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the usb drive activity light startup?

Potentially the hub is defective or it is unable to provide power to devices that are not self-powered.